Why does this SQL code not result in a syntax error? What use could this have?
A coworker and I were looking at a script that didn't work and we were pretty stumped. I have boiled it down to an MVCE here
Declare @JLTable TABLE
(
  JLID  int identity(1,1),
  JLName    nvarchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO @JLTable values ('Bruce')
INSERT INTO @JLTable values ('Clark')
INSERT INTO @JLTable values ('Diana')
INSERT INTO @JLTable values ('Shayera')
INSERT INTO @JLTable values ('John')
INSERT INTO @JLTable values ('John')
INSERT INTO @JLTable values ('Wally')

DECLARE @JohnIDs TABLE
(
    id int
)

INSERT INTO @JohnIDs
SELECT JLID
FROM @JLTable
WHERE JLName = 'John'

SELECT * FROM @JLTable
where JLID IN (SELECT JLID from @JohnIDs)

We have a proper table (@JLTable above), and an in memory list of specific ID's in that table. We then wanted to do some operations on only those rows. We did this by doing an update...where in..., but we made a typo and selected the JLID column out of the actual proper table, instead of the ID column in our temp table. That said, we didn't get a syntax error, it appeared to select the JLID column out of the @JLTable variable even though we specified the @JohnID's table. I'm confused as to why I'm even allowed to do that selection -- I can't think of a feature or flow where this would add any clarity.

That's why you should use column with aliases in your code, it avoids a lot of silly mistakes

... i.e. qualify all columns, like t.col. Also note the difference between a syntax error and a semantic error.
